# How to shut down the dispatcher thread in akka ActorSystem

Tags: scala, tomcat, akka

I'm using akka 2.1.2 via ActorSystem inside Tomcat and I'm having trouble shutting it down. I'm calling system.shutdown() which is shutting down the actual actors, but two akka threads are left behind and block Tomcat from stopping: scheduler and dispatcher.

I managed to shut down the scheduler by calling system.scheduler.asInstanceOf[DefaultScheduler].close() 
(cast required as the Scheduler trait does not have a close method). However, I can't figure out how to get the dispatcher thread(s) to stop. I tried the dodgy technique of making an object in the akka.actor package so that I could call system.dispatcher.shutdown() (a protected method), but that didn't work - there are still one or more akka dispatcher threads hanging around afterwards.

How can I shut down the dispatcher thread(s)? It doesn't have to be an ideal/correct way as long as it works.

Comment: As a very first step I would upgrade to 2.1.4 since that is a drop in replacement for 2.1.2.

Comment: Are you using `system.isTerminated` to check if the `ActorSystem` is really shut down?  The shutdown happens asynchronously to the `system.shutdown` call.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is some shutdown method, but there are two methods which can help. As it is written in the docs:

> When the dispatcher no longer has any actors registered, how long will it wait until it shuts itself down, defaulting to your akka configs "akka.

You can set `akka.actor.default-dispatcher.shutdown-timeout` in reference.conf and then `detach` you actor from your dispatcher.